# SQL UPDATE Statement(Syntax) error

Tags: sql

Hi I am busy with a project for school and would like to know something that I can't get to work.

I have Database with a table called Users and one called Animals and they are linked with a relationship. In the Animal table there is a column called UserID and it is linked to the name of the user. What I am trying to do is to give the user the abilty to adopt animals that have not been adopted yet. On the page where they can adopt is dbedits that is linked to the animal table and they display all the info of one animal and when you use the dbnavigator you go to next animal etc. DBedits shows a column value of the specified animal. One dbedit shows if the animal is adopted or not and when you click the adopt button next to it it says if the animal is adopted and if it is not you can adopt it. When it's not adopted the user can put his name in a InputBox and this name I want to put in the animal table where it says userID, because if you then look in the user table there is a "+" icon next to the users and when you click the "+" icon of the user that adopted the animal it should display the relevant animal's information. Behind the adopt button I get the user's name with an inputbox and put it in a variable called username and the animal's name I get with one of the dbedits and put it in a variable called nameofanimal. Then I want to change the userID in animal table to the user's name where the animal's name = nameofanimal, but it does not work. I am using ADOQRY and here is the SQL UPDATE code I am using,

```
qryDBV.sql.Text := 'UPDATE Animals SET Adopted = Yes AND UserID = '''+username+''' WHERE (('''+nameofanimal+'''[Adopted] = false)';
     qryDBV.ExecSQL;
     qryDBV.Active := false;
     qryDBV.sql.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Animals';
     qryDBV.Active := true;
    end;
```

Comment: `AND` is used in `where` clauses and `YES` is needs to be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first line with this..
AND used in where clause only...
So the code will be like this..

```
qryDBV.sql.Text := 'UPDATE Animals SET Adopted = Yes , UserID = '''+username+''' WHERE (('''+nameofanimal+'''[Adopted] = false)';
```

Comment: I still get the same error message and delphi highlights this line,  qryDBV.Active := false;

Answer (score 0):

1. Always put quotes around your strings.
2. Dont use AND in your SET clause but in your WHERE clause if needed
3. Escape your quotes when needed

`qryDBV.sql.Text := 'UPDATE Animals SET Adopted = 'Yes', UserID = \''+username+'\' WHERE (\''+nameofanimal+'\'[Adopted] = false)';`